# Mobile redirection using htaccess not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mobile, subdomain

I have a website called http://www.mydomain.com.au

And a mobile sub domain www.m.mydomain.com.au

I use following htaccess codes

```
    #Mobile Redirection
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m\.mydomain\.com\.au$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://m.mydomain.com.au/ [L,R=302]
```

Problem is when I type http://www.mydomain.com.au/anyurl from mobile it is not redirecting to mobile site. I just need to divert all pc website urls to my mobile website  home page www.m.mydomain.com.au

Any help pls.

Answer (score 0):

Think that if your mobile site url is  www.m.mydomain.com.au
  you should write :

```
#Mobile Redirection
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.m\.mydomain\.com\.au$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://www.m.mydomain.com.au/ [L,R=302]
```

If it does not work, could you post your 2 vhosts ?

Regards;

mimiz